# Application validation You must supply an apple id - uploading app on app store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

when I try to validate my application through xCode after archiving it says "you must supply an apple id" while I used correct `apple id` and correct `password` .

[image]

I am using xCode 5.1.1

Answer (score 9):

Ignore it, it'll submit just fine

Answer (score 1):

My solution is very horrible, I spent around 1 hr by applying above technique and search for other ways.

But it worked after restarting Xcode.

Same failed validation build successfully uploaded on server after restarting Xcode.